# TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, exception, .net-assembly, system.configuration

I am using the app.config file to store credentials and when I try to retrieve them, I get a `TypeLoadException` as follows :

> Could not load type 'System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler'
>   from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

It's a .NET 4.5 project, I set the `System` and `System.Configuration` `Copy-Local` attributes to `true`, and I don't understand where the problem comes from. I'm not experienced in .NET programming, so not very at ease with the concept of assembly.

Here are the snippets of code :

*app.config*

```xml
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="Credentials">
   <section name="Twitter" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<Credentials>
 <Twitter>
   <add key="****" value="*****"/>
   <add key="****" value="*****"/>
  </Twitter>
</Credentials>
```

*Connecting service file*

```
var hashtable = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Credentials/Twitter");
```

I know it is a common issue, and I googled it before posting. But all the solutions I've found so far don't seem to work, or I may not have understood them correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "type" attribute is malformed, it needs to be the fully qualified type name:  "System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Comment: That is it ! I already tried that but I think I forgot one of the elements. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

With reference to [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245(v=vs.100).aspx) you need to use `Fully qualified class name` in `app.config` as Hans said. In your code it would be

```
<sectionGroup name="Credentials">
   <section name="Twitter" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
</sectionGroup>
```